# Can't get string from object in Node.JS

Tags: express, mongoose

I try connect my MongoDB database. I use Node.js with Express.js.
I try create schema and parse object into JSON, but doesn't work.
This is index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var util = require('util');
var serwer = new mongodb.Server('127.0.0.1', 27017);

var mesons;

new mongodb.Db('test',serwer).open(
        function(err,client){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Polaczyles sie baza Mongo');
            mesons = new mongodb.Collection(client,'mesons'); 
});

var mesonsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Name: String,
    Mass: String,
    Charge: String, 
    LifeTime: String,
    AntiParticle: String,
    Type: String,
    Width: String,
    IJPC: String,
    MagneticMoment: String

});

var mesonsModel = mongoose.model('mesons', mesonsSchema );

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     return mesonsModel.find(function( err, mesons) {
         if( !err ) {
             return res.json( mesons );
         } else {
             console.log( err );
             return res.json( { error: 'No data returned'} );
         }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I connect localhost there is no results, no errors and loading and loading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you start a mongoose connection to the database. It looks like the connection is not made so the `mesonsModel.find` call is just hanging.
Instead of connecting directly with the mongodb drive you can connect via mongoose:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test');
```

You can wait to see if the connection is successful by listening for the open event:

```
mongoose.connection.once('open', function (callback) {
  // now you can query the database
});
```

You should remove the whole `mongodb.Db()` call